# Light for the capslock key on a HP 430

Tags: laptop, capslock

I have a HP 430 Laptop and the light on the Caps Lock stopped working. I had to type something to know if the Caps Lock is turned on/off.

To get the HP support I need to get the product # and the serial #, so I removed the battery from the laptop and when I put it back in, the light on the Caps Lock started working again.

Why didn't restarting my computer fix the light? why did I need to remove the battery (and put it back in) to fix it? The problem is fixed, but just curious as to why.

Comment: Just a guess; but the inside of keyboards get very funky. Maybe just the process of turning it upside down, giving it a virtual kick by snapping the heavy battery  back in, might have dislodged a little bit of krud blocking the led switch connector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's also possible that the hardware was in a bad state, which was being maintained by virtue of the battery being connected. After you remove the battery, all state is lost after a few moments.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what [jdh](https://superuser.com/users/115651/jdh) said, something may have been blocking the connection to light, or the connection to the light may not have been complete.

I'm assuming that to needed to turn the laptop onto its back to remove the battery, and in doing so, something may have been dislodged, became lodged once again.